# Awarding a bounty when you're no longer using the code you asked about

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have asked a question on Stack Overflow about a pagination problem with some jQuery code, and set a bounty of 100 on it.

Later I decided to choose another approach with different jQuery code.

But people are answering my question, and now I can't decide who should be awarded the bounty.
What should I do in this case?

My question: 
[trying to call an alert at window bottom for pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838636/trying-to-call-an-alert-at-window-bottom-for-pagination)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but later i decided to choose another similar jquery

If I understood you correctly, you no longer use (or require) the code in the question which the answers are for.

In that case, choose which ever answer you feel deserves the bounty as if your circumstances *hadn't* changed and you still required the answer for the code/scenario in the original question.

> I can't decided to whom to give bounty reward

This is your decision really, it's a personal choice based on why *you* feel someone would deserve it.

I might say answer X was the best, someone else answer Y, and you might feel answer Z was better. Which is why you need to decide yourself as it is *you* who is awarding it to an answer based on how much the answer helped *you and your scenario*.

Good code, good description, demos, code comments, directly answers your question, code provided works perfectly for you, etc.